# store binary file to hbase with pig

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, binaryfiles

I have some binary file with ".spc" pattern, and I would like to store these files into HBase with pig mapper job. The rowkey is file name.

Here are commands I used:

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs-directory/sampleID-uvvis.spc' USING BinStorage();

B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS rowkey;

C = GROUP B BY rowkey; 

STORE C INTO 'hbase://test3' USING BinStorage('colfamily:uvis');
```

And I got the error like below:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2116:
<line 12, column 0> Output Location Validation Failed for: 'hbase://test3 
More info to follow:
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hbase
```

I also checked the file after load:

```
Dump A
Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records (3353 bytes) from: "hdfs-directory-uvvis.spc"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs-directory/tmp/temp-
707332811/tmp1004712115"
```

Can someone help me with this issue? How to load and store the binary file into HBase?

I am new to HBase and pig job, any idea will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage** class for storage. Take a look at this example

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html

Comment: thank you for the reply, I tried to use the new class for storage. The storage process works!!! However, I think I still have error with data load, here is what I got: " Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records (3353 bytes) from: "hdfs-directory/sampleID-uvvis.spc"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hbase://test3"